# PHP - How to re-encode a URI

Tags: php, url-encoding

I *think* I have the need to take a uri which has been decoded in PHP, and re-encode it.

Here is the situation:

1. JavaScript passes encoded uri as query string parameter to php script.
2. PHP script embeds uri as a hidden input value in an html document, responds with the document to a user agent.
3. JavaScript reads embedded uri and sets location of current document based on value of hidden input.

On Step 2, I am finding that the Uri is fully decoded after reading it in via $_GET.  So when I embed the uri in the hidden input, it becomes un-encoded.  So I would like to run a PHP script which re-encodes the Uri properly ex:

```
http://my.example.com/dog walk?is=very great

==>

http://my.example.com/dog%20walk?is=very%20great
```

Is there a pre-built php function for this or should I just write my own?

**PLEASE NOTE:** urlencode and urldecode are not the answer to get the desired input/output I have in the example above.

Thanks,
Macy

Comment: How do you encode the URI with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if will help you, but PHP have 3 useful functions:

```
$url = parse_url('put the url here');
parse_str( $url['query'], $query ); // generating an array by reference (yes, kinda weird)
echo $query; //in this line, you can encode or decode.
```

or, if you want to mount a query, you can use http_build_query(); that accepts values from an array, like:

```
$url = 'http://my.example.com/dog walk?';
$array = Array (
 'is' => 'very_great',
);
$url_created = $url . http_build_query($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the most useful, see original post for what I devised.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for : http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php ?

Comment: This works when you pass an entire URI?  I thought it only worked when you passed a single parameter value.

Comment: Yeah, this does not perform the desired functionality, in my example above, it produces: http%3A%2F%2Fmy.example.com/dog%20walk?is%3Dvery%20great which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: In fact, the only part that doesn't need encoding is the protocol. I would just replace %3A%2F%2F with :// . This should do the job.

Comment: If you are not looking for urlencode, I don't think there is a function in PHP to do that. You should do it by yourself... Use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to remove it from your URL, do the urlencode on the remaining string and concat it again with $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ...

Answer (score 0):

urldecode:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Please read question carefully, especially desired input/output.